# Конфиг OpenVPN со стороны клиента имеет ошибку, но какую?

Tags: linux, vps, openvpn, openvz

На стороне клиента имею такой конфиг:

```
client # указываем, что нужно работать в режиме клиента

remote X.X.X.X 443 # указываем, на какой порт нужно подключаться
proto  udp # указываем протокол передачи пакетов
dev    tun # указываем тип сетевого интерфейса

remote-cert-tls server # исключение возможности mitm-атак, путем проверки серверных сертификатов

ca       ca.crt 
cert     client.crt
key      client.key
tls-auth ta.key 1

auth-nocache # не кэшировать пароли в памяти

comp-lzo # сжатие трафика для экономии полосы пропускания
mssfix 0 # скрыть VPN fingerprint

persist-key # не перепроверять файлы ключей
persist-tun # не изменять tun/tap устройства

verb 3
```

При запуске подключения OpenVPN выдает ошибку и такую запись в логе:

> Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in
>   client.ovpn:1: ﻿client (2.2.2) Use --help for more information.

Какой-то параметр в конфиге лишний или чего-то не хватает? Не могу понять...

Конфиг сервера:

```
port  443 # значение порта на котором будет работать сервер
proto udp
dev   tun

ca       /etc/openvpn/server-keys/ca.crt
dh       /etc/openvpn/server-keys/dh2048.pem
key      /etc/openvpn/server-keys/server.key
cert     /etc/openvpn/server-keys/server.crt
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/server-keys/ta.key 0

server 172.16.150.0 255.255.255.0 # подсеть сервера, диапазон которого будет использоваться для выдачи адресов клиентам
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" # указываем клиентам что в качестве шлюза по умолчанию нужно использовать шлюз VPN-сервера

keepalive 10 120 # пинг клиентов и перезапуск туннеля

#compress lz4-v2 # сжатие для версий OpenVPN 2.4.+ и ниже
#push "compress lz4-v2"

comp-lzo # сжатие для версий OpenVPN 2.4.+ и выше
mssfix 0

persist-key
persist-tun

log    /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
mute 20
```

Сразу добавлю, что работаю на VPS (OpenVZ), а дистрибутив:

```
root@olala:~/openvpn-ca/keys# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-042stab127.2 (root@kbuild-rh6-x64.eng.sw.ru) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 16:41:44 MSK 2018
```

Comment: Дима вы, смотрю, уже 4й день мучаетесь с OpenVPN вам принципиального именно его использовать? StrongSwan или WireGuard хорошие замены. Если коефиг редактируете на винде там может быть другое окончание строк в кодировке.

Comment: @Hellseher, да, принципиально на OpenVPN) Редактирую на Linux и я возможно уже знаю проблему, просто не написал сюда ответ, т.к. еще нет возможности проверить наверняка, т.к. есть еще одна проблема, которую я уже скоро из безысходности сюда запилю)

Answer (score 0):

Со стороны клиента в конфиге никаких проблем не было, как и в конфиге со стороны сервера.

После сброса сервера и настройки на нём OpenVPN с нуля (с тем же конфигом), эта ошибка больше не появлялась.

Сначала думал, что мб OpenVPN не включен на сервере и поэтому ошибка появляется, но даже если OpenVPN не включен, то подключение все равно пытается сделать, а этой ошибки нет.

В целом причину этой ошибки так и не выяснил, но она успешно устранена :)